# How to get coordinates dynamically in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, imagemapster

I am working on image mapster, but when I do the following I get NaN for coords.

```
<div id="rts" class="largWin"><a href="a.html" class="close">&times;</a>

<center><img id="floo-map1" src="img/plan.jpg" alt="Floor plan in Pan Pacific Level 4" border="0" width="750" height="472"  usemap="#floorplan-conference-map1" style="width:750px; height:472px;"/></center>
<map id="image_map1" name="floo-map1">
<script>
  function getx()
  {
    return 425,78,483,116 ;
  }
</script>
<area id = "try" name="gg" full="ggh" shape="rect" coords=getx() href="#">
</map>
</div>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know much about imagemapster, but 425,78,483,116 is not a number. I don't know if it's looking for an array but there is clearly something wrong with that

Answer (score 0):

Thats not how javascript works. you dont return its value to *area* thats why you getting NaN because coords is not getting anyvalues.

instead change the values inside the getx()

```
 document.getElementById("try").coords = "425,78,483,116";
```

But why do you want to change its coords in javascript to begin with?

Or try Try coords="return getx()"

Comment: I need the coords to be changing dynamically

Comment: Try      coords="return getx()"

Comment: @anand if you want the coords to change, you need to "push" the coords (e.g.  document.getElementById("try").coords = "425,78,483,116") *whenever* you want them to change, the area object won't "pull" the updated data. You can't simply name a function in the coord attribute and expect it to be called, you need to make the update yourself - usually either on a timer or when the source data changes.